# Problem making nested .js module files work

Tags: javascript, typescript, import, module, referenceerror

I seem to be going in circles trying to get a simple nested .js files to work.  I start with these 2 files and it works as expected:

*index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type="module" src="./scripts/file1.js"></script>
    <title>Hello World Page</title>
</head>
<body >
    <div>
        Some prompt: <input id="Xxx" onkeyup="file1Go('index.html calling file1Go()')"/><br />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

*file1.js*

```
function file1Go(msg) {
    alert('In file1.js - ' + msg);
}
```

Then I create a new `file2.js` and modify `file1.js` to import it. I also modify it to export the function that is used.  I then also modify the `index.html` file's script tag to tell it that `file1.js` is now a module like this (to avoid the '*Cannot use import outside of a module*' error):

```
    <script type="module" src="./scripts/file1.js"></script>
```

Modified *file1.js*

```
import { file2Go } from "./file2.js"
export function file1Go(msg) {
    alert('In file1.js - ' + msg);
    file2Go(msg);
}
```

New *file2.js*

```
 export function file2Go(msg) {
    alert('In file2.js - ' + msg);
}
```

This results in the html page loading and both .js files downloading without error, but at runtime it fails to find the exported function in file1.js:

```
(index):11 Uncaught ReferenceError: file1Go is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onkeyup ((index):11)
```

That's it.  What stupid thing am I doing wrong or what am I missing?
And thanks in advance for taking the time.

*Afterthought:* Putting similar .js files in a folder and executing with node.js appears to work.

**More Info:**

I've discovered that the following `<script>` tag does import and execute the function. I can also set HTML event handlers there.  It's just that functions are apparently not visible outside of the scope of the `<script>` tag which to my little brain appears to be unduly restrictive and unuseful.

```
    <script type="module">
        import { file1Go } from "./scripts/file1.js";
        file1Go("logging on start in <head> tag...");  // works
        document.getElementById('Xxx').onkeyup = file1Go;  // also works
    </script>
```

*Note: My endgame here is to use `TypeScript` which would have many files. I removed `TypeScript` from my repro for simplicity and to target the root cause of my issue. Once I understand the scoping issue I'll move on to `TypeScript`.*